# How to disable unauthorised and automatic connections to extensions.gnome.org?

Tags: networking, gnome, configuration, settings, privacy

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and using version 17.10 with Gnome 3.26.2 in a VirtualBox VM. Occasionally (once a day?) an unauthorised and automatic connection to "extensions.gnome.org" on port 443 is executed (I catch it with a network monitor on the macOS host).

How can I disable this highly unwanted and privacy-invading behaviour? I've spend hours searching for the magic switch for this one without luck.

It is not related to any settings I can control with the `Software & Updates` application. There are also no options to disable it with something in the `Settings` application. Additionally I already installed the `dconf Editor` application and made sure that the value of `org/gnome/software/download-updates` is set to false (which seems to be the default.) Additionally `org/gnome/shell/disable-extension-version-validation` is at the default value of "true".

---

**Update:** when I block the request (e.g. via macOS) then following is dumped to the Ubuntu syslog: *"gnome-software[1693]: failed to call gs_plugin_refresh on shell-extensions: [*/*/*/source/shell-extensions/*] failed to download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json: Cannot connect to destination"*

---

**Update #2:** `chrome-gnome-shell` and potential browser add-ons for the GNOME Shell integration are not installed on my system.

Comment: Just add `extensions.gnome.org` to the hosts file (in Ubuntu), and point it to `0.0.0.0` - ?

Comment: @JonasCz I don't want to block it entirely. I might want to visit that website one day. I just don't want it do regularly connect by itself for no reason there in an automatic fashion.

Comment: @Haru when that day comes, just undo that modification to hosts